# Is the C Data Type REAL only available in GCC?

Tags: c, gcc

I'm currently trying to build an iOS App using the linpack C source.

While going through the original [source](http://www.netlib.org/benchmark/linpackc) I came over the data type REAL which I never met before. After investigating some time I recognized it's available through GCC but unfortunately not in XCode (or it's standard C Compiler).

This is why I'm wondering if REAL is only available on gcc or if there's any way to make this compatible with Xcode or other compilers.

Comment: `REAL` is #define'd at the very top of that source file to be a `float`.

Comment: Voting to close as a problem that cannot be reproduced (the answer is in the file posted by the OP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the preprocessor directives at the beginning of the file, you'll see that `REAL` is actually a macro, defined as either `float` or `double`. So, it's specific to this file, not to gcc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Seems as I have overseen this. Will accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The first few lines of the source you provide `#define` the macro `REAL`:

```
#ifdef SP
#define REAL float
#define ZERO 0.0
#define ONE 1.0
#define PREC "Single "
#endif

#ifdef DP
#define REAL double
#define ZERO 0.0e0
#define ONE 1.0e0
#define PREC "Double "
#endif
```

The macros `SP` and `DP` are probably being defined on the command line like so:

```
cc -DDP -c linpack.c
```

If you `#define` neither `SP` nor `DP`, the compiler will complain like it did in your case.

Comment: Odd, I would expect there to be an explicit `#if !(defined(SP)||defined(DP)) #error`. Putting it in a code comment instead is silly.

Comment: @Sneftel It's old code judging by the fact that it doesn't even use `typedef`. I suspect that some pre-ANSI preprocessors didn't implement `#if` correctly and didn't provide `#error`.